# Promise-all for array paths images

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, promise.all

```
let newArr = [];
let paths = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'];
function promiseAllImg(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = arr[i];
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            image.addEventListener('load', function() {
                resolve(image);
            })
            image.addEventListener('error', function() {
                reject('error');
            })
        }) 
    }           
}

newArr.push(promiseAllImg(paths));
Promise.all(newArr).then(function(res) {
    for (let i = 0; i< newArr.length; i++) {   
        document.body.appendChild(res[i])
    }
})
```

I need to show all images, but this programm shows only the first image. What is the problem in my programm? Write a code that will wait until all the images are loaded, and then add them in a loop to the end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning inside a `for` loop.

During the first iteration of the loop, the code hits `return` and returns which ends the function.

You should replace the `for` loop with [the `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of your array.

That will run a function for each item in an array and then return an array containing all the results (i.e. the promises).